# Logistic modeling with censored predictors

Tags: censoring

What are not-too-complex methods to perform logistic modeling if some of the predictors are right-censored?

Comment: Maybe multiple imputation will work, in particular, see https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/other-data-types.html#sec:censored